# cygwin introduces spaces in the console output when running a maven build for a java project in windows 10

Tags: java, windows, maven, cygwin

Check the following output fragment from a cygwin64 terminal on windows 10 64bit while running a maven 3 build using java 1.8:

```
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\proj\t020-domain\src\          test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ t020-domain ---
m
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source f          iles to C:\proj\t020-domain\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ t020-domain                                     ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.2:jar (default-jar)                                @ t020-domain ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\proj\t020-domain\target\t020-domain-80.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:prepare-agent-integration (default-prepare-agent-integration) @
36mt020-domain ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:C:\\Users\\VBO07\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.4\\org.jacoco.agent-0
.8.4-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\proj\\t020-domain\\target\\jacoco-it.exec
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.2:integration-test (default) @ t020-domain ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.2:verify (default) @ t020-domain                                           ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:report (default-                            report) @ t020-domain ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:report-integration (def                            ault-report-integration) @ t020-domain
 ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:check (default-check) @ t020-domain ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to mi          ssing execution data file:C:\proj\t020-domain\target\jacoco.exec
```

You can see it clearly happening on the lines:

```
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\proj\t020-domain\src\          test\resources
```

and

```
[INFO] Compiling 2 source f          iles to C:\proj\t020-domain\target\test-classes
```

and

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:report (default-                            report) @ t020-domain ---
```

and

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:report-integration (def                            ault-report-integration) @ t020-domain
```

and

```
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to mi          ssing execution data file:C:\proj\t020-domain\target\jacoco.exec
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: This also happens for JDK 11–15

Answer (score 1):

After posting this problem on cygwin's website, Marco Atzeri gave a solution that works for me: set in windows's environment variables:

```
CYGWIN="disable_pcon"
```

Then, obviously, restart cygwin.

**EDIT:**

The above solution has a big bad side-effect: if you need to run interactive commands with `cmd /C`, then the then above flag will kill the interactions (waiting for input for example will not work anymore). A better solution that does not have this problem was posted by Takashi Yano on cygwin as answer to my question: replace the jar `jansi-1.17.1.jar` in the lib folder of maven with `jansi-2.1.1.jar`. You can download the 2.1.1 version from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/2.1.1